# Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, hudson, jakarta-mail, jenkins

I'm trying to configure my e-mail on Jenkins/Hudson, and I constantly receive the error:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be
    non-empty
```

I've seen a good amount of information online about the error, but I have not gotten any to work. I'm using Sun's JDK on Fedora Linux (not OpenJDK).

Here are a few things I've tried. I tried following the advice from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764611/java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-trustanchors-parameter-must), but copying the cacerts from Windows over to my Fedora box hosting Jenkins didn't work.  I tried following [this guide](http://g4j.sourceforge.net/faq.html) as I'm trying to configure Gmail as my SMTP server, but it didn't work either. I also tried to download and move those cacert files manually and move them over to my Java folder using a variation of the commands on [this guide](http://www.krzywanski.net/archives/546).

I am open to any suggestions as I'm currently stuck right now. I have gotten it to work from a Windows Hudson server, but I am struggling on Linux.

Comment: I don;t know if this helps but I have had this happen in DBeaver and just had to fix it, which apparently also uses java as its nightmare of choice.  There were 3 options in driver configuration: Require SSL, Verify Server Certificate, Allow Public Key retrieval. When I uncheck Verify Server Certificate the connection succeeds, prior it was giving this same error for any but a root connection to mysql 8.0.

Answer (score 607, accepted):

This bizarre message means that the trust store you specified was:

- empty,
- not found, or
- couldn't be opened, due for example to:

  - wrong/missing `trustStorePassword`, or
  - file access permissions.

See also @AdamPlumb's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25188331/207421).

Comment: I'll add a twist: even when the truststore exists, is accessible, is in the right format, if it is COMPLETELY EMPTY, that's the error you can get with various libraries (including Apache HttpClient).

Comment: btw this happens e.g. when switching from OracleJDK8 to OpenJDK8 since OpenJDK comes with an empty trust store. Copying the one from OpenJDK11 fixes the problem

Comment: Can also happen if you run Oracle JDK8 but set your JAVA_HOME to OpenJDK8.

Comment: This can also happen when using a PKCS12 key store and no password (= `null`) is provided when the store is loaded, see [source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/f99414c0526c44e48d6b16494cb16b50e30b6317/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/pkcs12/PKCS12KeyStore.java#L2034)

Answer (score 302):

In **Ubuntu 18.04**, this error has a different cause (JEP 229, switch from the `jks` keystore default format to the `pkcs12` format, and the Debian cacerts file generation using the default for new files) and [workaround](https://gist.github.com/mikaelhg/527204e746984cf9a33f7910bb8b4cb6):

```bsh
# Ubuntu 18.04 and various Docker images such as openjdk:9-jdk throw exceptions when
# Java applications use SSL and HTTPS, because Java 9 changed a file format, if you
# create that file from scratch, like Debian / Ubuntu do.
#
# Before applying, run your application with the Java command line parameter
#  java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit ...
# to verify that this workaround is relevant to your particular issue.
#
# The parameter by itself can be used as a workaround, as well.

# 0. First make yourself root with 'sudo bash'.

# 1. Save an empty JKS file with the default 'changeit' password for Java cacerts.
#    Use 'printf' instead of 'echo' for Dockerfile RUN compatibility.
/usr/bin/printf '\xfe\xed\xfe\xed\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe2\x68\x6e\x45\xfb\x43\xdf\xa4\xd9\x92\xdd\x41\xce\xb6\xb2\x1c\x63\x30\xd7\x92' > /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

# 2. Re-add all the CA certs into the previously empty file.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

---

**Status (2018-08-07)**, the bug has been fixed in Ubuntu Bionic LTS 18.04.1 and Ubuntu Cosmic 18.10.

---

[Ubuntu 1770553: [SRU] backport ca-certificates-java from cosmic (20180413ubuntu1)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1770553)

[Ubuntu 1769013: Please merge ca-certificates-java 20180413 (main) from Debian unstable (main)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1769013)

[Ubuntu 1739631: Fresh install with JDK 9 can't use the generated PKCS12 cacerts keystore file](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1739631)

[docker-library 145: 9-jdk image has SSL issues](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/145)

[Debian 894979: ca-certificates-java: does not work with OpenJDK 9, applications fail with InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=894979)

[JDK-8044445 : JEP 229: Create PKCS12 Keystores by Default](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8044445)

[JEP 229: Create PKCS12 Keystores by Default](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/229)

---

If the issue continues after this workaround, you might want to make sure that you're actually running the Java distribution you just fixed.

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

You can set the Java alternatives to 'auto' with:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -a
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so
```

You can double-check the Java version you're executing:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 10.0.1 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

---

There are alternative workarounds as well, but those have their own side effects which will require extra future maintenance, for no payoff whatsoever.

The next-best workaround is to add the row

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

to the files

```
/etc/java-9-openjdk/management/management.properties
/etc/java-11-openjdk/management/management.properties
```

whichever exists.

The third least problematic workaround is to change the value of

```
keystore.type=pkcs12
```

to

```
keystore.type=jks
```

in the files

```
/etc/java-9-openjdk/security/java.security
/etc/java-11-openjdk/security/java.security
```

whichever exists, and then remove the `cacerts` file and regenerate it in the manner described on the last row of the workaround script at the top of the post.

Comment: This answer helped me to fix same error with maven on Ubuntu 18.04. I had to change owner of /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts file from root to myself to be able write to it. Then I switched it back.

Comment: I ran **sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts** and then **sudo update-ca-certificates -f** and this fixed my issue in kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @jsn Thank you for the fix! For future readers: this works for openjdk-8-jdk, but not for openjdk-11-jdk. Seems like /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore doesn't seem to support openjdk-11 (it isn't listed there).

Comment: @jsn , thanks for the solutions , works on linux mint 19 as well which is based on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with Java 11.

Comment: @jsn's solution also worked for Debian Stretch + openjdk8

Comment: I changed the Java version for NiFi from an Oracle version to a more modern OpenJDK and it worked

Comment: the third solution helped me a lot, but if you added how to regenerate cacerts, it would be much greater. "sudo update-ca-certificates -f" and "sudo apt install ca-certificates-java --reinstall" which i found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971059/17-10-openjdk-and-oracle-jdk-8-and-9-the-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empt)

Comment: I struggled with this for days.  `sudo update-ca-certificates -f` and `sudo apt install ca-certificates-java --reinstall` fixed it for me on maven Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 112):

This fixed the problem for me on Ubuntu:

```
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

(found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1396760)

`ca-certificates-java` is not a dependency in the Oracle JDK/JRE so this must be explicitly installed.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue for me when I ran into it on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Worked on Raspbian on Raspberry Pi

Comment: Ran into this issue with Debian jesse stable backports with OpenJDK8 and this fixed the issue. Was using this while building Docker images. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I get `command not found` when I try this on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what I just did, but this fixed the issue for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Atlassian Bitbucket Server v4.9.1 on Debian Jessie (8.6) behind Firewall had the same problem. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Worked on an Artifactory install on Ubuntu 14.04. Before this command, attempting to add a remote repository threw the trustAnchors error. After this command, smooth sailing :)

Comment: Fixed for me on Ubuntu 14.04.  Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu MATE 18.04, sadly. I will try reinstalling Java.

Comment: Doesn't work in Xubuntu 18.04 too. Seems like will not work in any 18.04. Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: Any idea guys, what to do in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Run `sudo apt install ca-certificates-java` . Then `sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure`

Comment: @codefx - I've done what you suggest and it doesn't work - on Ubuntu 18.x with Java 10 (default).

Answer (score 77):

On Ubuntu 18.04 the root cause is a conflict between openjdk-11-jdk (which is default) and other packages depending on it. It has already been fixed in Debian and will be included in Ubuntu shortly. Meanwhile the simplest workaround is to demote your java to version 8. Other solutions employing `ca-certificates-java` are much more complicated.

First remove conflicting packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk* java-common default-jdk
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Check whether you successfully removed all related packages by:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

The system shall prompt you **there is no Java available to config**, otherwise this workaround **fails**.

Then reinstall required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: This description is factually incorrect, and only fixes the problem in the same sense as reinstalling Windows might fix an issue. There is no need to remove all Java packages. If you want to go this way, you only need to install the `openjdk-8-jdk` package, remove the `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` file, and run `sudo update-ca-certificates -f` which is the roundabout way of switching from a `pkcs12` formatted cacerts file to a `jks` formatted one, as described elsewhere in this thread.

Comment: @MikaelGueck While the logic seems to be on your side, I'm here to assure you I previously did exactly what's described in your comment and in the most other voted answers, and in 18.04 **this is the only answer which worked**. I think your downvote should turn into an upvote, or at least vanish, since it's highly undeserved.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, you can read through the scripts yourself, they are pretty short. They have a hardcoded set of JAVA_HOME paths from 8 to 10, they try those one at a time, they call the Debian CA file generator which you can also read through, which uses the existing file format, because the JDK keyfile handler code, which you can read through, has a compatibility fallback mode. If your computer runs this simple software differently, you might have other problems with it. Did you modify your java alternatives, and call some other JVM, because then removing might have reset the alternatives?

Comment: @MikaelGueck yes, in one of the previous tries I've modified my java alternatives, so it probably was that. I'm the first who likes to dig into source code and find how stuff works, but this today was not my goal, it was just one among 5-6 different unexpected obstacles I had in the way to my real goal.  This answer allowed me to solve the problem in less than 2 minutes! How much time should I have put to look into scripts and find a better solution? And for what, to save some megabytes? This is drastic, but works (and no matter what the problem is), so a big thank to OP for those busy as hell

Comment: when actually executing the 2 purges and seeing the list of packages that apt was removing this seemed a bit heavy handed to me however it did the trick for my unimportant kubuntu 18.04 install so i'm happy

to save a small amount of typing i used `sudo apt-get purge openjdk* java-common default-jdk` rather than `--purge remove`

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Also I had to make sure the $JAVA_HOME is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

Comment: I have been looking for a solution for 2 days, and your answer solved my issue, thanks. I just move to Kubuntu 18.04, this worked on it.

Comment: Downloading jdk worked for me. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk13-downloads-5672538.html

Answer (score 66):

EJP basically answered the question (and I realize this has an accepted answer), but I just dealt with this edge-case gotcha and wanted to immortalize my solution.

I had the `InvalidAlgorithmParameterException` error on a hosted [Jira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jira_(software)) server that I had previously set up for SSL-only access. The issue was that I had set up my keystore in the PKCS#12 format, but my truststore was in the JKS format.

In my case, I had edited my `server.xml` file to specify the keystoreType to PKCS, but I did not specify the truststoreType, so it defaults to whatever the keystoreType is. Specifying the truststoreType explicitly as JKS solved it for me.

Comment: well, I help you immortalizing solution to your edge-case gotcha. that's where it gets interesting.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I was using Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, and had a hardware keystore and software truststore. I specified the provider and type for the keystore, but not the truststore. As a result, the wrong provider and type were used by the truststore. Specifying those (SUN and JKS) solved the issue.

Comment: how exactly did you do this? (windows here)

Comment: Run into this with my Android grandle today, i almost understand  what you say but you don't say how to solve it. Non helpable answer

Comment: in my case I had a trusttore generated by jdk 14 keytool, defaults to pkcs format, trying to connect to kafka cluster that is using a jks keystore.  I amend how I created the truststore to use switch `-storetype jks` and it resolved it

Comment: Yeah, default storetype in `keytool` changed with java9, causing my previously working solution to generate PKCS12 instead of required JKS.

Answer (score 53):

I ran into this solution from blog post *[Fixing the trustAnchors problem when running OpenJDK 7 on OS X](http://architecturalatrocities.com/post/19073788679/fixing-the-trustanchors-problem-when-running-openjdk-7)*:

Fixing the trustAnchors problem when running OpenJDK 7 on OS X. If you're running OpenJDK 7 on OS X and have seen this exception:

```
Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
    parameter must be non-empty
```

There's a simple fix. Just link in the same cacerts file that Apple’s JDK 1.6 uses:

```
cd $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)/jre/lib/security
ln -fsh /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
```

You need to do this for every OpenJDK version you have installed. Just change `-v 1.7` to the version you want to fix. Run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see all the JREs and JDKs you have installed.

Perhaps the OpenJDK guys could add this to their install scripts.

Comment: My "ln" command (on OSX 10.6.8) doesn't have an "h" option; what is it meant to do?

Comment: Ah, I had two "ln" commands, one in /usr/bin (the default) and one in /bin; the latter had an "h" option and worked.

Comment: I fixed my broken 1.6 installation linking to cacerts from the system 1.8 installation with this ln technique. Thanks!

Comment: For future readers: it seems that you also need the other 3 files that are in the `security` folder (`blacklisted.certs`, `local_policy.jar`, and `US_export_policy.jar`) for Java to be happy.

Comment: @Peter Kriens, why linked to `cacerts` under `jre` directory?

Comment: So in the case of Java 1.6, the path where you want to create the links may be different. In my case, I've installed it manually from a compressed ZIP, so my installation point was actually this: 
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`
and the folder where I've created the symbolic links to `cacerts` and `blacklisted.certs` files was this `lib/security`. After providing these links, the issue is corrected.

Answer (score 48):

In [Ubuntu 12.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29) (Quantal Quetzal) or later, the certificates are held in the [ca-certificates-java](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/ca-certificates-java) package. Using `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` will pick them up regardless of what JDK you're using.

Comment: I found I needed to run `update-ca-certificates -f` manually, to populate the cacerts file

Comment: @Portablejim Thanks.  Your comment solved the first issue I hit building Apache Spark on Ubuntu 15.04beta.

Comment: Thanks you  @Portablejim, your comment worked for me on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Thanks. This is fixed my problem with PhpStrom + patched JDK. I wrote this key into  "phpstorm64.vmoptions" file.

Comment: Not working for me in ubuntu 18.04 and JDK is 1.8.0_62

Comment: This solution worked also for me running a Bitbucket Server on a Hetzner System with debian. I used this line to force java to run with the trustStore 
  
  
`export ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`

Comment: thank you - i had no idea and didn't even consider that ubuntu ca-certificates utils would also create a java JKS bundle

Answer (score 35):

I ran into this exact problem on OS X, using JDK 1.7, after upgrading to [OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks). The fix that worked for me was to simply reinstall the Apple version of Java, available at http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572.

Comment: I encountered this with Java 6 used by Grails on OSX. I also had Java 7 from Oracle installed and also upgraded to Mavericks. Re-installing Java 6 from Apple website also fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Ran into this when installing open jdk 6 onto an ubuntu cloud box. Nice to see a familiar face, BTW

Answer (score 31):

The error tells that the system cannot find the truststore in the path provided with the parameter `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`.

Under Windows I copied the `cacerts` file from `jre/lib/security` into the Eclipse install directory (same place as the `eclipse.ini` file) and added the following settings in `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
```

I had some troubles with the path to the cacerts (the %java_home% environment variable is somehow overwritten), so I used this trivial solution.

The idea is to provide a valid path to the truststore file - ideally it would be to use a relative one. You may also use an absolute path.

To make sure the store type is JKS, you would run the following command:

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN
```

**Note**: because certificates have expiration dates, or can become invalid for other reasons, do check from time to time if the certificates in *cacerts* are still valid. You would usually find the valid versions of the certificates in the latest builds of jdk.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually worked. Thanks @razvanone

Comment: I managed to hit one small "gotcha": The three lines in the eclipse.ini file must be on actual three separate lines. I initially put all of them on one line and eclipse did not pick that up.

Comment: I managed to fix this error that occurred even though all there JVM args were set. When inspected the path to the cacerts.jks was not correct in my eclipse.ini file. So even wrong jks path can generate this error. Fixing to correct jks path solved the error

Comment: mine was `PKCS12`, not `JKS`. Open JDK21, coming with eclipse. mentioning store type fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

I ran

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

to create a certificate file, and then:

```
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

I was back in business, thanks guys. It is a pity it's not included in the installation, but I got there in the end.

Comment: When I run `sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure**` I get `sudo: /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst: command not found`

Comment: Just `sudo update-ca-certificates -f` is enough on Debian jessie with `openjdk-8-jre-headless` from jessie-backports, as long as `ca-certificates-java` is installed. I think order of installation matters (JRE after `ca-certificates-java` may cause this, as the latter doesn’t have any triggers for the backported Java 8).

Comment: `sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure`  without stars **

Comment: `update-ca-certificates -f` is the thing that fixed it. I didn't need the 2nd command

Answer (score 18):

Removing the ca-certificates-java package and installing it again worked for me ([Ubuntu MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE) 17.10 (Artful Aardvark)).

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java

sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

Thank you, jdstrand: *Comment 1 for bug 983302, Re: ca-certificates-java fails to install Java cacerts on Oneiric Ocelot*.

Answer (score 16):

For me it was caused by the lack of a trustedCertEntry in the truststore.

To test, use:

```
keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks
```

It gives me:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

cert-alias, 31-Jul-2017, PrivateKeyEntry
```

Even though my PrivateKeyEntry contains a CA ***it needed to be imported separately***:

```
keytool -import -alias root-ca1 -file rootca.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

It imports the certificate, and then re-running `keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks` now gives:

```
Your keystore contains 2 entries

cert-alias, 31-Jul-2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): <fingerprint>

root-ca1, 04-Aug-2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): <fingerprint>
```

Now it has a trustedCertEntry, and Tomcat will start successfully.

Comment: NB check baeldung tutorial with a useful Makefile as shortcut to creating keystore & truststore (spring-security-x509 project) https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security

Answer (score 14):

Some OpenJDK vendors releases caused this by having an empty `cacerts` file distributed with the binary. The bug is explained here: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/555

You can copy to `adoptOpenJdk8\jre\lib\security\cacerts` the file from an old instalation like `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\lib\security\cacerts`.

The AdoptOpenJDK buggy version is https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-releases/releases/download/jdk8u172-b11/OpenJDK8_x64_Win_jdk8u172-b11.zip

Comment: I think this was the case for me as well. In AdoptOpenJDK 202 this bug is present, and in 222 it works. So update your jdk if possible.

Answer (score 11):

I've had lot of security issues after upgrading to [OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks):

- SSL problem with Amazon AWS
- Peer not authenticated with Maven and Eclipse
- `trustAnchors` parameter must be non-empty

I applied this Java update and it fixed all my issues: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Ugh. Java 6 is many years past its end of public support, and is surely riddled with security holes. Apple makes it available for download so that older software that cannot be run with Java 7/8 can continue to execute, but it should not be used for making SSL connections to services on the public internet, such as 1. AWS, 2. Maven Central, 3. anything else.

Answer (score 10):

I expected things like this, being that I use an alternate JVM in my [Talend Open Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talend_Open_Studio_for_Data_Quality#Talend_Open_Studio_for_Data_Quality_Project) (support at the moment exists only until JDK 1.7). I use 8 for security purposes... anyway

- Update your certificate store:

  ```
  sudo update-ca-certificates -f
  ```

then

- add a new value in your initialization parameters

  ```
  sudo gedit $(path to your architecture specific ini i.e. TOS_DI...ini)

  Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
  ```

For me, the second entry worked. I think, depending on the version of Talend Open Studio/TEnt + JVM, it has a different parameter name, but it looks for the same keystore file.

Comment: Where did you get the property `javax.net.ssl.trustAnchors` from? It isn't mentioned in the JSSE documentation.

Answer (score 8):

If you experience this on Ubuntu with JDK9 and Maven, you can add this JVM option - first check if the path exists:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

If the file is missing, try to install the ca-certificates-java as someone noted:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates-java
```

Comment: If you use docker then you may also try "maven:3-jdk-9-slim" image instead of "maven:3-jdk-9"

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me for openjdk-8-jdk in ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6):

I had this error message on Java 9.0.1 on Linux. It was due to a known bug of the JDK, where the cacerts file is empty in the .tar.gz binary package (downloaded from http://jdk.java.net/9/).

See the "known issues" paragraph of *[JDK 9.0.1 Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-0-1-relnotes-3883752.html)*, saying "TLS does not work by default on OpenJDK 9".

On Debian/Ubuntu (and probably other derivaties), a simple workaround is to replace the cacerts file with the one from the "ca-certificates-java" package:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates-java
cp /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts /path/to/jdk-9.0.1/lib/security/cacerts
```

On Red Hat Linux/CentOS, you can do the same from the "ca-certificates" package:

```
sudo yum install ca-certificates
cp /etc/pki/java/cacerts /path/to/jdk-9.0.1/lib/security/cacerts
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm a fan of portability, so I don't install java, just download the tar.gz and export some values in the path and everything works.

I fought with this issue and no solution (install or update operative systems certs). Nothing worked for me.

### cacerts file is empty

In my case, reviewing my jdk folder, the cacerts file had a little size compared with other jdk folder (servers & friends):

`/../some_openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts` **size: 32 bytes**

I downloaded it from:

- https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8u41/ri/openjdk-8u41-b04-linux-x64-14_jan_2020.tar.gz
- https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk9/9/binaries/openjdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

### Fix

After several attempts I found a correct jdk.tar.gz with a **cacerts** file with size **101 KB**

I downloaded the **open jdk** from [https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-upstream-binaries](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-upstream-binaries/releases)

- https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-upstream-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u262-b10/OpenJDK8U-jdk-jfr_x64_linux_8u262b10.tar.gz

I found this url in this Dockerfile :

- https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/b5d14d9165fad693901c285d6e7bbc36d1cde41f/8/jdk/Dockerfile

Comment: for the same issue my cacert had 0 entries , so having the right cacerts resolved my issue

Answer (score 5):

In my case the JKS file used in the client application was corrupted. I created a new one and imported the destination server SSL certificates in it. Then I used the new JKS file in the client application as a trust store, like:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",path_to_your_cacerts_file);
```

Source: [Java SSL and certificate keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore)

I use the (KeyStore Explorer) tool to create the new JKS. You can download it from this link, [KeyStore Explorer](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/).

Comment: [keystore-explorer](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/index.html) did the work for me. You just have to create default keystore and examine and save the certificate file for the site/host.

Comment: For some unknown reason on windows OpenJDK11, OracleJDK 11 i had to do the same, did it on the parameters: "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts"

Answer (score 5):

You may also encounter this error after upgrading to Spring Boot 1.4.1 (or newer) because it brings along [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) 8.5.5 as part of its dependencies.

The problem is due to the way that Tomcat deals with the trust store. If you happen to have specified your trust store location as the same as your keystore in the Spring Boot configuration, you'll likely get the `trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty` message when starting the application.

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server.jks
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:server.jks
```

Simply remove the `server.ssl.trust-store` configuration unless you know that you need it, in which case consult the links below.

The following issues contain more details about the problem:

- *[HTTPS Tomcat connector fails to start with 1.4.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7069)* #7069
- *[SSL-client-auth with self-signed cert stopped working](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7406)* #7406
- *[Upgrade to Tomcat 8.5.5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6703)* #6703

Comment: This solution saved my life today, Thank you soo much.

Comment: This does not explain how having same keystore set as trust store breaks things.
Links imply this might be due to empty trust store which doesn't seem to be the case. Don't see how it's all related.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when trying to use [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) 3, after upgrading from [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) LTS (Xenial Xerus) to [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) LTS (Bionic Beaver).

Checking /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security showed that my cacerts file was a symbolic link pointing to `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`.

I also had a file suspiciously named `cacerts.original`.

I renamed `cacerts.original` to `cacerts`, and that fixed the issue.

Comment: The `cacerts.original` file was in the `jks` format, and was generated with Ubuntu 16.04's Java 8, which used that format as its default. The `cacerts` file was in the `pkcs12` format, generated by Ubuntu 18.04's Java 10, which uses this format as its default. As explained elsewhere in this thread, the new format requires you to pass the password to the executable. But as long as you either generate a new empty `jks` `cacerts` file or copy an old one, the next cacerts generation process will empty the existing file out, and refill it with the CA certificates from the file system.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this on OS X after updating OS X v10.9 (Mavericks), when the old Java 6 was being used and tried to access an HTTPS URL. The fix was the inverse of Peter Kriens; I needed to copy the `cacerts` from the 1.7 space to the location linked by the 1.6 version:

```
(as root)
umask 022
mkdir -p /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security
cp $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)/jre/lib/security/cacerts \
    /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security
```

Comment: The command here tries to copy a directory to a file; makes no sense at all.

Comment: I concur with the assessment of using a reverse solution. I found that jdk1.6 had a broken softlink /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_33-b03-424.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -> /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts.  So I rm'ed the broken soft link, then copied over the cacerts from the jdk1.7 installation.

Comment: NOTE: when you are done you should be able to cat the cacerts file that you copied to validate the permissions.

Comment: Also, fixed the cp to go the right direction and added the umask for mkdir and cp.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem with the Android SDK sdkmanager. For me this solution worked:

1. Go to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/`
2. Replace `cacert` with `cacert.original`

The `cacert` file was a tiny one (22B). I have installed `oracle-java8-installer` from `ppa:webupd8team/java` (according to this manual: https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-linux).

Answer (score 3):

[Marquis of Lorne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788682/7914761) is accurate, I'm adding some info for debugging purposes:

To debug this issue (I wrote about it with more details in [here](https://medium.com/@gustavocalcaterra/debugging-yet-another-ssl-tls-error-the-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty-7dd9cb300f43)) and understand what truststore is being used (or trying to use) you can add [the property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug) javax.net.debug=all and then filter the logs about truststore. You can also play with the property javax.net.ssl.trustStore to specify a specific truststore. For example :

```
    java -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Another/path/to/cacerts -jar test_get_https-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar https://www.calca.com.py 2>&1| grep -i truststore
```

Answer (score 2):

On Red Hat Linux I got this issue resolved by importing the certificates to `/etc/pki/java/cacerts`.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Users\\user-id\\Desktop\\tomcat\\cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "passwd");
```

You have to add the above two lines to your code. It is not able to find the truststore.

Comment: If you don't, it will use the JRE truststore, and it will certainly be able to find that. The error is caused by incorrect values in these parameters, not their absence. The file named in your code only applies to your installation, not generally.

Comment: The proper way to set those properties are by passing them on the command line: `java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/cacerts ...` or if you want to set them globally for all programs run with a JDK, add the row to the JDK's `management.properties` file.

Comment: I faced the same issue and this solution was right. But I start my application with vm options: 
`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts.jks`
`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit`

Answer (score 2):

For the record, *none* of the answers here worked for me. My Gradle build started failing mysteriously with this error, unable to fetch HEAD from [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) [central](https://central.sonatype.org/) for a particular [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file.

It turned out that I had JAVA_HOME set to my own personal build of OpenJDK, which I had built for debugging a javac issue. Setting it back to the JDK installed on my system fixed it.

Comment: ... which caused the truststore not to be found, as per other answers.

Comment: Yeah, but knowing that the truststore can't be found is entirely unhelpful if you do can't figure out *why* it's not being found.  There are many many possible ways it can go wrong, and it's frustating when none of them happen to be the particular way that it is failing for your own system.

Comment: They all 'happen' to be the same error: the truststore specified could not be opened or was empty. There are a million ways in which this situation could arise, and there isn't enough space on SO to enumerate them all.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I needed to use OpenJDK 1.7 for the maintenance of an old project. I downloaded the binary package. But when I executed my script on it I got the same error.

The solution was to remove the `cacerts` file of the downloaded JDK in the `jre/lib/security` folder and then to create it as symlink to the systems `cacerts` file in `/etc/ssl/certs/java/`:

`sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts /path/to/downloaded/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Answer (score 2):

Slim chance this will help anyone but....for anyone running Java 8 from a Docker Image on a Raspberry Pi (using AMD CPU) I got the following Dockerfile to build and run successfully for me

```
FROM hypriot/rpi-java
USER root

WORKDIR /usr/build/

RUN /usr/bin/printf '\xfe\xed\xfe\xed\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe2\x68\x6e\x45\xfb\x43\xdf\xa4\xd9\x92\xdd\x41\xce\xb6\xb2\x1c\x63\x30\xd7\x92' > /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
RUN update-ca-certificates -f
RUN /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

EXPOSE 8080

ARG JAR_FILE=target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Fall into this using Amazon SDK v2, Windows 10 and JDK8.
Amazon SDK was complaining about credentials loading.
I solved this by replacing the `security/cacert` file of JDK8 by the JDK11 one.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem while running a particular suite of Android for testing on [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr). Two things worked for me as suggested by shaheen:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f

sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

Answer (score 1):

None of solutions that I found on the Internet worked, but a modified version of [Peter Kriens's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty/10915692#10915692) seems to do the job.

First find your Java folder by running `/usr/libexec/java_home`. For me it was the `1.6.0.jdk` version. Then go to its `lib/security` subfolder (for me `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security`).

Then delete the `cacerts` file if there is one already and search for one on the system with `sudo find / -name "cacerts"`. It found multiple items for me, in versions of Xcode or other applications that I had installed, but also at `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts` which I chose.

Use that file and make a symbolic link to it (while inside the Java folder from before), `sudo ln -fsh "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts"`, and it should work.

I have both - Java from Apple's 2017-001 download (https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572 - I assume that's where the correct certificates are from) and Oracle's one installed on [Mac OS X v10.12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra).

Answer (score 1):

on ubuntu 14.04 with openjdk 11 from ppa:openjdk-r/ppa this worked for me:

in java.security change keystore type to

```
keystore.type=jks
```

then:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

when you check if it worked, be sure you are not using any daemon with old java still running (eg. `--no-daemon` option for gradle)

this bug describes everything nicely and will help you understand what's going on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1739631

Comment: a system reboot is also required it seems after all this steps

Answer (score 1):

I found yet another reason for this error, which is not related to Ubuntu.

I tried setting up mutual TLS in a Spring boot 2 app and ran into this issue after using a truststore that had only a private key entry and no trusted certificate entry.

This is my Spring Boot TLS configuration

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=oba-tls
server.ssl.key-password=mypw
server.ssl.key-store-password=mypw
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keys/tls-keystore.pfx
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.client-auth=need

server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:keys/truststore.pfx
server.ssl.trust-store-password=mypw
server.ssl.trust-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.ciphers=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
```

For generating truststore.pfx I had to use the following commands to make it work.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key -x509 -out cert.crt

keytool -importcert -alias oba-trust -file cert.crt -keystore truststore.jks

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore truststore.jks -destkeystore truststore.pfx -srcstoretype JKS - deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass yourpassword
```

Comment: A truststore that had only a private key entry and no trusted certificate entry isn't a truststore at all. It is a keystore.

Answer (score 1):

I ran

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

to create a certificate file, and then:

```
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure`
```

and then change the command line of jar execution:

```
sudo java -cp xx.jar:lib/* co.com.ixxx.clixxxlarxa.Main
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. But when I restarted the Tomcat service, thankfully it has gone.

```
sudo /usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
sudo /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the issue while importing a Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA 14.
A solution was using a local copy of Gradle instead of a wrapper from the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when sending emails, but **NOT** always. In my case I've changed one line of code to get a new [Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Session.html) object every time:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator));
```

to

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(props, authenticator));
```

Since then sending e-mails works every time.

The error I got:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;    
>   nested exception is:     javax.net.ssl.SSLException:               
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:                      
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors 
>   parameter must be non-empty     at                                 
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)     at 
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)  
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)     at 
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)     at        
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)     at        
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)     at      
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu:

> sudo apt install ca-certificates-java

or

> sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java

sorted it for me.

Comment: Johnny's answer (above) and then running your answer did the job for me. I am on LInux Mint using OpenJDK

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this is it's actually a valid error. Some nefarious Wi-Fi hotspots will mess with certificates and [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) you to do who knows what (run away!).

Some large employers will do this same trick, especially in sensitive network zones so they can monitor all the encrypted traffic (not great from end user perspective, but there may be good reasons for this).

Comment: The error is caused by a missing truststore file. It has nothing to do with wifi hotspots.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using a truststore which was exported using a IBM Websphere JDK keytool in #PKCS12 format and trying to communicate over SSL using that file on an Oracle JRE.

My solution was to run on an IBM JRE or convert the truststore to JKS using an IBM Websphere keytool, so I was able to run it in an Oracle JRE.

Answer (score 0):

For me it got resolved just by upgrading a Jenkins plugin, "Email Extension Plugin", to the latest version (2.61).

These two plugins are responsible for email configuration in Jenkins:

- *Email Extension*
- *Email Extension Template*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and the problem was not in configuring the JDK, but a simple wrong path to the JKS file in `application.properties` file under `trust-store:` parameter, double-check if the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case root cause of this issue was **empty truststore** (it was app server truststore).
When I added any **dummy x.509 certificate** then stopped throwing this error.

Command to add certificate in truststore vis keytool

```
keytool -import -alias dummy -keystore <path to keystore> -storepass <truststore password if any>
```

Comment: Why not add a real one? You aren't going to get anywhere with either an empty truststore or one that doesn't contain anything you actually need to trust.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the *the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty* error when I tried to run my app in IntelliJ. To fix the problem I had to make the Run Configuration point to the JDK or JRE that had the `/lib/security/` folder which had the `cacerts` file.

Comment: please provide an example of a solution

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had to explicitly specify the path to the store, but I didn't need to do this before. The application connects to the remote service over https.

Comment: And how could I, for a client application, specify this via properties (application.yml) ?

Answer (score 0):

With me, problem is settings.xml file for maven is not config right user
First check the settings file you use for build and check this with right user