# Exception when authenticating to Google Drive using Java API

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm having some problems while uploading a .txt file with Google Drive API. Here's my code:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class DriveCommandLine {

    private static String CLIENT_ID = "client_id";
      private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "client_secret";

      private static String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
            .setAccessType("online")
            .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

        String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
        System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
        System.out.println("  " + url);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String code = br.readLine();

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

        //Create a new authorized API client
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

        //Insert a file  
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle("Document Example");
        body.setDescription("This is a test of Google Drive SDK");
        body.setMimeType("text/plain");

        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
      }

}
```

The problem it's in this line:

```
GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
```

And the errors are:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1836)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1794)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1777)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1296)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1273)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1087)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:895)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:299)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:147)
    **at DriveCommandLine.main(DriveCommandLine.java:43)**
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:314)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:173)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:186)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1319)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:966)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1262)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1289)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:88)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with google drive api, but seems like it might complaining about something related to the truststore and certificates. Maybe double check you've created the truststore with appropriate certs? Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this sample (that is for Google Application based on localhost (client-side)) with methods provided for WebApplication. You need to instantiate a Google Web Application (server-side using HttpServlet) and use the redirect URI for a doGet method to catch automatically the code and exchange data to get the correct Authorization. See [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/authorization) and [OAuth 2.0 for WebApplication](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer?hl=it)