# Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, salesforce, websphere

Hie,

I wrote a java code which connects to **Salesforce** and updates a value in there, Its is working well and good when i run it from my local system as a **standalone java application** but my main goal is to take that as a **java component in filenet BPM workflow** , so when the workflow process gets to this **java component then it throws a error as the title**

the entire stack stack trace is as follows

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/24.0/0DF90000000PX8r
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:129)
    at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.login(EnterpriseConnection.java:1052)
    at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.<init>(EnterpriseConnection.java:399)
    at salesforceupdate.SalesForceUpdate.main(SalesForceUpdate.java:70)
    at salesforceupdate.Callin.UpdateSL(Callin.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at filenet.vw.integrator.adaptors.java.VWJavaAdaptor.execute(VWJavaAdaptor.java:426)
    at filenet.vw.integrator.base.VWAdaptorEx$AdaptorAction.run(VWAdaptorEx.java:120)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:727)
    at filenet.vw.integrator.base.VWAdaptorEx.run(VWAdaptorEx.java:360)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at com.ibm.jsse2.n.a(n.java:42)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:96)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:340)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:555)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:510)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.startHandshake(tc.java:381)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:151)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:64)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1024)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:51)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectRaw(JdkHttpTransport.java:115)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connect(JdkHttpTransport.java:79)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:107)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.<init>(e.java:117)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.d.a(d.java:20)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hc.a(hc.java:58)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hc.checkServerTrusted(hc.java:88)
    at filenet.ws.utils.jsse.FnTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(FnTrustManager.java:156)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:382)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:23)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.n(gb.java:295)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.a(gb.java:269)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:347)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.g(tc.java:416)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:60)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:287)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:143)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:101)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.<init>(e.java:17)
    ... 32 more
```

I have googled everything regarding this error and generated a **.crt** file of the domain and created a **keystore** file and mentioned that in my code

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer\\java\\jre\\bin\\secure.ts");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "xxxxx");
```

By the way i even modified **key managemnet and certificates in WAS console**

But I keep on getting the same error..Don't know what to do , Any help would be great

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you seen this? Different configuration but I hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty

Comment: For your information, the IBM security properties are specified like this:

com.ibm.ssl.keyStore
com.ibm.ssl.keyStorePassword
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreType
com.ibm.ssl.trustStore
com.ibm.ssl.trustStorePassword 
and so on....

Comment: @RobertHöglund So you are saying i that i have to set the keystore properties and then truststore ones?

Comment: The order of the properties does not matter. Just specify the properties an be sure to specify the correct values. Then use the java.security.debug property to further track down your problem.

Comment: @RobertHöglund yeah , i tried giving as you said but the same appears

Answer (score 10):

This error message usually means that your specified truststore can not be read. What I would check:

- Is the path correct? (I'm sure you checked this...)
- Has the user who started the JVM enough access privileges to read the
  trustore?
- When do you set the system properties? Are they already set when the webservice is invoked?
- Perhaps another component has overridden the values. Are the system properties still set when the webservice is invoked?
- Does the trustore contains the Salesforce certificate and is the file not corrupt (e.g. check with `keytool -list`)?

**Edit:**

- Don't use `System.setProperty` but set the options when starting the Java process with `-Djavax.net.ssl.XXX`. The reason for this advice is as follows: The IBM security framework may read the options **before** you set the property (e.g. in a `static` block of a class). Of course this is framework specific and may change from version to version.

Comment: In my case this was because of the wrong location of the keystore as stated in this answer. Be careful with unnecessary prefixes such as file:/

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

> - In my case, I have 2 duplicate Java installations (OpenJDK and
>   JDK-17).
> - I installed JDK-17 after configuring environment variable for OpenJDK and before uninstalling OpenJDK.
> - So, maybe that is the problem.

This is how I SOLVED it **in my case:**

- First, I have completely removed openJDK and JDK-17 from my computer (including JDK-17/lib/security/cacerts).
- Then, I deleted the java environment variable and restarted the computer.
- Next, I thoroughly checked that there aren't any JDKs on the computer anymore.
- Finally, I just reinstalled JDK-17 (JDK-17/lib/security/cacerts is default).  And it worked fine for me.

**Note:** kill any Java runtime tasks before uninstalling them.