# trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, ssl, https, jboss, ssl-certificate

***trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty***

I'm trying to find the solution for this exception over a week, but I can't.

I'm running a JBoss 7.0.13 (let's call as APP-SV|app.my.site.com), and what I need is to comunicate to with another JBoss 7.0.13 (this is "WS-SV"|webservice.my.site.com). Both are Windows Server 2003.

APP-SV consumes webservice (this JBoss is running as HTTPS )
WS-SV expose the services (this JBoss is also running as HTTPS, ***with the same certificate which APP-SV use (a wildcard *.my.site.com)***

From the APP-SV I can't execute the webservice. It's show "***trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty***".
Out of JBoss (.Net app and one Java Class) I could execute with success the webservice.

The keystore configuration (standalone.xml) is:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
    <ssl name="ssl" key-alias="tomcat" password="123456" certificate-key-file="..\\standalone\\configuration\\.keystore" protocol="TLSv1"/>
</connector>
```

1 - The keystore exists? *YES*

2 - The password is correct? *YES*

3 - Have permission? *YES*

4 - "cacerts" exists and have certs? *YES, and it's non-empty*

What else you try?

I tried

- create another keystore - fail
- change the directory of keystore - fail
- use java code System.setProperty to change keystore and password - fail

Nothing work.

I don't know what else I can do. 
With these repeated failures, I'm not sure that these couple of things I did, is "the thing" I need to do. Maybe I cannot see some details...

*Sorry for any typo or grammatical error...*

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Comment: yes, I already read this too

Comment: Well it contains the answer, which makes this question redundant.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that where ever you are indicating the path to the keystore, it is an incorrect path.  Basically, it can't even find the file to try and open it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ed Sandoval, but it was 2 years ago, and I can't remember what was the solution, but I think it was about two versions of JAVA. Consequently two "cacerts".

Comment: I don't think so. When I test this with a bogus file name, Tomcat throws a `FileNotFoundException` instead.