# SSLException while accessing rest web services

Tags: java, rest, session, ssl

I have a requirement to access a https URL on startup of my server using jax-rs to get some unique session key. However, once the session is expired i will again fire the hit to this URL and get my session key back.

I noticed that while I send the request to get the expired session back, I get this error.

```
     javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException:             
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:  
 java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the 
 trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

In this scenario if I start my server, I am all good with my session key back. Please advise how to analyze this issue and how can I reproduce this issue as required to handle exception well in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the trust store file is not there, there but not with the necessary permissions for this process. Check out this link:

[Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Comment: I agree it might be a good use case for testing. In this problem, if its a issue with store file, I shouldn't be even getting the session in active state on server restart!

Comment: does your program use setuid or something akin - perhaps that user does not have access?

Comment: I use the same userid to get my session token during application startup or to reactivate the session when session expires.

Comment: Just to make sure that we are talking about the same thing. Am assuming this is a *nix, and am talking about the user that starts the server and if it takes on a different user and possibly different set of permissions.

Comment: Yep we are on same page. same user with same permission.