# Maven error with maven-clean-plugin

Tags: java, linux, apache, maven

I'm new to maven and i'm trying to use the following command :

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

but i get the following error :

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.0.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]

I have absolutly no idea of what i'm missing. Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
            <groupId>net.sf.okapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-okapi-superpom</artifactId>
            <version>0.30-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <relativePath>superpom/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>build-okapi-root</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Okapi Build Root</name>
    <url>https://bitbucket.org/okapiframework/okapi</url>

    <modules>
            <module>superpom</module>
            <module>okapi</module>
            <module>okapi-ui/swt</module>
            <module>applications</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

My maven version :

```
mvn -v
    Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5;   2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
    Maven home: /root/apache-maven-3.3.9
    Java version: 1.7.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
    Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "linux", version: "3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: It seems you have this an issue with your truststore for some reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6788682/2492865

Comment: Is anybody confirm that this issue could be resolved or not? Thank you!