# Leiningen fails to install dependencies on OS X Yosemite: "InvalidAlgorithmParameterException (trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty)"

Tags: macos, clojure, leiningen

I was installing Clojure on a Mac running OS X Yosemite (10.10.5). Following the recommended procedure, I first installed Leiningen. While running `lein deps` for the first time, I got a series of errors such as this:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.8.0 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

The same baffling error message appears in a number of other StackOverflow questions relating to specific software other than Leiningen, Clojure, and OS X  and the accepted answers in those cases appear to be very different from what worked for me (e.g. [Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)), so I have created a new question for this specific problem to help others trying to install Clojure on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the Java runtime that comes with OS X Yosemite.

First get rid of all the Java Virtual Machines installed:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/*.jdk
```

Then install a reliable Java runtime with the Mac package manager, [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew update
brew cask install java
```

After this, simply enter `lein deps` again - it then works fine (or at least, it did for me).