# Maven failed to download dependencies after adding dependency to pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

What is the correct way to add dependency in Intelli?
I have added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

to pom.xml but I got the error

> Failed to execute goal on project accessing-data-mysql: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.e
> xample:accessing-data-mysql:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:sprin
> g-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.4.7: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring
> -boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.4.7: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-config
> uration-processor:pom:2.4.7 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://
> repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/2.4.7/spring-boot-conf
> iguration-processor-2.4.7.pom: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParam
> eterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]

when I do `mvn install`. I have try maven->reload project and it still didn't work. Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788295/maven-error-repeated-java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-tr

Comment: i think your spring version not support this version from your dependency

Answer (score 0):

After a failed attempt, maven will leave a small file in your local .m2 repository that will prevent any attempt to re-download the file unless the update interval has elapsed or you force the updates using the maven -U switch described in other answers.

Just delete the folder for that artifact in your local m2 repository and update you project; a new download attempt will trigger.

rm -rf ~/.m2