# Error in mail function, the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: ssl, grails, smtp

***Hello, i'm working in Grails and i got a error when i try to send a mail.***

This is the error.

*server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465 (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty). Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465 (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty)*

**CODE CONTROLLER**

```
try{
        log.info("Segundo mensaje")
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = (ByteArrayOutputStream)pdfRenderingService.render(template: "/cotizador/print", model:[ordenTransmisionInstance:ordenTransmisionInstance,total:params.total,imagen:imagen.bytes])

    mailService.sendMail {
        multipart true
        to params.email
        subject "Correo de cotización de productos"
        body "A continaución se adjunta un archivo con la información de cotización."
       attachBytes "cotizacion.pdf", "application/pdf", bytes.toByteArray()
    }
   }catch (Exception e){
        log.info("Tercer mensaje" + e.getMessage())
        flash.message = message(code: "send.email.fail.error", default: "Ha ocurrido un error por favor intente nuevamente.")
    }
```

**Config.groovy**

```
    grails {
mail {
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 465
    username = "******"
    password = "******"
    props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
}
```

}

Comment: Did you just post your Gmail username and password on a public forum?

Comment: Thanks but they don't work!! :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty

Comment: The configuration you are using is correct. Seems that you have network problems, maybe a firewall which is blocking the connection?

Comment: omg. @tim_yates did you try to login with that? And have to agree to quindimildev - the code seems correct.

Comment: I've seen a good amount of information online about the error, but have not gotten any to work.