# Gmail doesn't proceed mail sending from java application

Tags: java, spring, gmail

I have a java Spring web app from which I send emails using my Gmail account credentials. Everything worked fine until I migrated my site from DigitalOcean to AWS EC2. Now when I try to send an email I get the following error:

```
    ERROR SendMailServiceImpl:48 - Error sending mail: 
      org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
      nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
      nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty; message exceptions (1) are: Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
      nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Here is my mail sender configuration:

```
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="587"/>
        <property name="username" value="myAccount@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value="myPassword"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I have "untrusted applications allowed" enabled in my Gmail account. But I get the same error again and again. Moreover when I lunch my application locally then everything works fine and I don't get any errors

looks like this is some kind of gmail restriction for remote hosts

does anybody know how to fix this?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty

Comment: this is a different question