# Error connecting Jenkins to GitLab: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I encounter the following error when trying to test the connection to GitLab:

```
Client error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException:
```

I am using Jenkins as a snap from Ubuntu Software Center on my localhost and running oracles java 8 jre.
I added my ssh-key and the api-token under credentials:
[image]

Whenever I want to test the connection the following error is displayed:
[image]

I already tried to `update-ca-certificates` and use the open jdk but the error still remains.

Comment: Have a look at answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty

Comment: @VladimirL. Thanks, I tried some of the answers but none of them helped so far. I verified to have the symbolic link set correctly `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 Mär 27  2016 cacerts -> /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` and also updated the ca-certificates again. I tried using openjdk-7/8 and oracle-8 and the alternative is correctly set `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Jul  9 19:03 java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`.
I also tried to point to the certs and trustStore using JAVA_ARGS="..." when trying to run the jenkins.jar -> doesn't help either :/.