# Obtaining Azure Access Token for German Cloud

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-sdk

I have a small program which fails while trying to obtain the Access Token for the Azure German Cloud

```
public static String generateAccessToken(AzureAccount accountValue) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException,
                    ExecutionException, ServiceUnavailableException {
        AuthenticationContext context;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            String tenantId = accountValue.getTenant();
            String ClientID = accountValue.getClient();
            String secretKey = accountValue.getKey();
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            context = new AuthenticationContext(
                                                "https://login.microsoftonline.de/" + tenantId
                                                + "/oauth2/authorize", false,
                                                service);

            ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential(ClientID, secretKey);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future =
                                                context.acquireToken("https://management.microsoftazure.de", cred,
                                                                     null);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = future.get();
            if (authenticationResult == null) {
                throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
            }
            System.out.println("Bearer " + authenticationResult.getAccessToken());
            return "Bearer " + authenticationResult.getAccessToken();
        }
        finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

The code works correctly for the Azure General Cloud but is failing for the German Cloud.

This is the stackTrace

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.configureHeaderAndExecuteOAuthCall(AdalOAuthRequest.java:140)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.send(AdalOAuthRequest.java:83)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:80)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:818)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:66)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:174)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 29 more
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.vmturbo.mediation.azure.Runner.generateAccessToken(Runner.java:127)
    at com.vmturbo.mediation.azure.Runner.main(Runner.java:79)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.configureHeaderAndExecuteOAuthCall(AdalOAuthRequest.java:140)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.send(AdalOAuthRequest.java:83)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:80)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:818)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:66)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:174)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
```

It looks like it is looking for some certificate file which I have no idea about. Does anybody have any idea about this ?

Also is there a way of obtaining the Azure Access token using the Azure Java SDK so that I don't have to make a REST API call individually ?

Comment: I would look through all the files in your project, even the ones you didnt write, and search for instances of "windows.net" or "microsoftonline.com" and make sure there are not configurations in your app pointing to the wrong Azure Cloud. I am not 100% sure about the error message, but it might be as simple as your program failing to validate the signature on the token as a result of you looking up the wrong public key endpoint.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, I just tested it as you have it and was able to obtain an access token to the Azure Germany management API. Are you completely sure this is where the exception is being thrown (you're missing part of the stack trace)? Have you looked at [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty) on StackOverflow regarding that exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you were using a VM not in the German IP range. You have two options:

1. Deploy a VM in Azure Germany cloud or in AWS Frankfurt
2. In order to deploy from a non-German location: update the Java SDK you have (I had 1.8.0_92 and updated to 1.8.0_144) and this should work

Comment: Hi did it fixed it? I have the same issue and I am running from Azure Germany VM using java 1.8.144

Comment: yes, after that you have to set your java jvm path again and then source the bash_profile script. Did you do that?

Comment: you can check by typing which java in terminal

Comment: i am using the latests java - 1.8.0.144 - i have installed java on clean machine