# OpenJDK9 (Docker), gradle 4.2.1, GitLab

Tags: java, docker, gitlab-ci, java-9

My project builds locally using graddlew 4.2.1. But when I git push it to the GitLab, I get the error below. **I have to use Docker and so I don't know what Docker Image I could use for this to work.** Also this is the gitlab-ci.yml:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# This template uses the java:8 docker image because there isn't any
# official Gradle image at this moment
#
# This is the Gradle build system for JVM applications
# https://gradle.org/
# https://github.com/gradle/gradle
image: openjdk:9-jdk

# Disable the Gradle daemon for Continuous Integration servers as correctness
# is usually a priority over speed in CI environments. Using a fresh
# runtime for each build is more reliable since the runtime is completely
# isolated from any previous builds.
variables:
    GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

# Make the gradle wrapper executable. This essentially downloads a copy of
# Gradle to build the project with.
# https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html
# It is expected that any modern gradle project has a wrapper
before_script:
    - chmod +x gradlew

# We redirect the gradle user home using -g so that it caches the
# wrapper and dependencies.
# https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html
#
# Unfortunately it also caches the build output so
# cleaning removes reminants of any cached builds.
# The assemble task actually builds the project.
# If it fails here, the tests can't run.
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew -g /cache/.gradle clean assemble
  allow_failure: false
  artifacts:
    name: "AudioBot"
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar
```

Here the error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty   at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:214)    at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1969)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1921)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1436)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1563)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1491)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:236)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:66)   at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:51)    at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)    at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)    at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)   at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>     at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty   at
>   java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:89)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:180)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:192)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:133)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.checkServerCerts(ClientHandshaker.java:1825)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.certificateStatus(ClientHandshaker.java:1676)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:272)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1086)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processRecord(Handshaker.java:1020)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.processInputRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1137)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1074)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1429)
>     ... 14 more Caused by:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty   at
>   java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.(PKIXParameters.java:120)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:86)
>     ... 29 more ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Comment: ok, well, but I'm using Docker. Isn't there any Docker image that can provide the required certs for graddlew and java9?

Comment: The build tool is called **gradle**, not **graddle**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug from maybe Debian in the Docker image. They working on it I think: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/145

To fix this right now, you can use the jdk-9-slim images. Just add the -slim.

Answer (score 1):

For testing, you can make one base on the [docker-library/openjdk](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/19) one.

See [`docker-library/openjdk issue 19`](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/19)
`ca-certificates-java.postinst configure` is supposed to be there since [PR 111](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/pull/111), but if another approach mentioned in "[Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6784463/6309)", you can test it out in your custom image.

Note that [moby/moby issue 18180](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18180) once impacted `ca-certificates-java.postinst configure`, but should b OK now.

Comment: tried adding the command to update the certs, but that didnt help: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25737403/ still the same. any other ideas? :)

Comment: This has a bug report: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/145 Thank you for the help! :)