# Eclipse / PyDev installation trouble on a new Ubuntu 17.10 ( certificates ?)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, certificate, ssl-certificate, pydev

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10, I try to install Eclipse CDT + Pydev.
I download Eclipse from eclipse.org : eclipse-cpp-oxygen-1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz .
After this, I usually go to Help > Install New Software > Add > http://pydev.org/updates, and then I can install pydev.

Today on this new PC :
In windows where I usually select "PyDev", I see only : "There are no categorized items" or "There are no items available" if is unset "group item by category".

I notice 2 unusually facts :

- if I add new plugin from Eclipse standard part, I have a window to confirm certificates from Eclipse
- in log (workspace/.metadata/.log), I have some message like :

```
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1002 2017-10-26 
    08:34:21.046
    !MESSAGE Unable to read repository at 
    https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/6.0.0/content.xml.
    !STACK 0
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected  
    error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1899)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
```

So it seems that I have certificate trouble ...

But now I need help :
  - is-it possible to put by hand missing certificates ? Where download theses certificates ? How to install ?

UPDATE :
I have download PyDev 6.0.0.zip from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/ .
I have unzip this file in my eclipse/dropin directory.
And I have PyDev installed.

PyDev is installed : my first problem is solved.

Why certificat is not accept ? It's a problem, but no more blocking me.

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty (does it fix it for you)?

Comment: Thanks for  stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/ , I have try every solution. I have still exactly the same thing ... I don't known  : it's a trouble o with -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustAnchors=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts    or if a cert file is missing in /etc/ssl/certs     and util today, I don't known nothing about certificate, it's just running

Comment: You can try to manually install (it should be possible to fix your java installation as it's a problem there, but not sure why that fix didn't work for you)... anyways, for the manual install, get the .zip and unzip in the dropins -- see: http://www.pydev.org/download.html for the links.

Comment: Fabio, have you seen update of information in message ? I have try to install manually, but it's still failed. More information in message.

Comment: You need to unzip the zip at the dropins.

Comment: Sorry for forgot to unzip file, and after this, PyDev is installed. Thanks.