# javax.net.ssl.SSLException - the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, gradle, openssl, openssl-engine

When I try to run `./gradlew run` I keep getting:

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Tried `curl -v https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-bin.zip`
and works just fine

```
Connected to services.gradle.org (2400:cb00:2048:1::6810:aba6)
successfully set certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which JDK or OS/distro you are using, but it's possible that `ca-certificates-java` is not a dependency in the Oracle JDK/JRE so this must be explicitly installed.

You might need to run

```
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

See also
[Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Comment: I'm using oracle-8-jdk on Ubuntu MATE 17.10, tried you command but still getting the error..

Comment: @Gavriil Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Have you found any answer for this. I am into this problem right now.