# Test to receive messages from existing SQS queue

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue and messages are written to the queue after an action.

After performing an mqtt unsubscribe, i want to access the sqs queue and check for a message.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,
            secretKey);
AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion(region).build();
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl);
List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest)
            .getMessages();
```

But i get the following error trusted parameters should not be empty:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1069)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1035)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1792)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1768)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1374)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1350)
at it.ITSubUnsubDisconnect.testUnsubscribeWithoutSubscribeDoesNottriggerSQS(ITSubUnsubDisconnect.java:156)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy11.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1190)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
... 57 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:88)
... 69 more
```

Any leads regarding the same would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following to get past the error regarding the security. Since mine is a test, i have allowed any host to be accepted.

If you have the certificate, it is best to use that instead of the below work around for the error.

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {

        @Override
        public boolean isTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            return true;
        }
    }).build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

    ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
    config.getApacheHttpClientConfig().setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

    AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion(region).withClientConfiguration(config).build();

    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest()
    .withQueueUrl(queueUrl).withMaxNumberOfMessages(10).withWaitTimeSeconds(10);
```

Comment: Note that this is not a safe solution, since it defeats the trust mechanism entirely.  You will likely, at some point, come to regret using this workaround.  See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/6784463/1695906 offers any solutions to this issue, which (to me) appears unrelated to SQS, *per se*.