# GitLab CI Maven dependency resolution fails

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, gitlab

I want to setup a CI pipeline in GitLab for my Java project managed with Maven.

This is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: maven:3-jdk-9

variables:
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"

stages:
   - build

compile:
   stage: build
   script:
       - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile
```

I always get the following exception:

[image]

I tried many things like changing versions of the plugins, various docker images, including a settings.xml and local repository in the project itself, but nothing works.

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

**UPDATE:**
Using the latest docker image everything works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the CI server has no connection to the internet. Check this using the `curl` command in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`file.

But I'm pretty sure you guys at daimler have a local mirror, something like [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/).
In that case you have to use a `settings.xml` file.
Here is the official tutorial of [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/artifactory_and_gitlab/index.html)

Comment: I checked the connection with `curl` on the resources plugin pom, works just fine. Unfortunately it has to work using the central maven repository.

Comment: Update: when using then latest docker image, everything works.

Comment: The error message means that no Truststore could be found. It is normaly located under '$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty#