# Error on executing mvn clean package: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, maven

I have a huge problem with Maven on my Ubuntu 17.10. In my pom.xml I use the maven-assembly-plugin. 
Every time I run Maven with `mvn clean package` in the root of my project the execution fails and in the Stack-trace I can find the error message

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

I already reinstalled Maven on my Ubuntu and searched through Google for many hours. It seems that Maven/Java can't connect to Maven Central over SSL. I found a way to use Maven and ignore SSL with `mvn clean package -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true` but this also didn't work.

The error occurs in all my Maven projects so I think the problem is not in the pom.xml.

The debug log with stacktrace is on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/K4eanQy4)

EDIT:
I checked my cacerts and found the .pem for digicert which validated the Certificate for Maven Central

[Posted an Screenshot here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0qa1.png)

Comment: you can try installing that plugin manually in your local maven repo. But if you have troubles connecting to the central one you will probably have more problems with other dependencies

Comment: What JDK are you using?

Comment: Yeah that would be possible, but I would also like to understand why this error is happening. And a quick fix would probably not fix all the problems. 

`java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
`

Comment: https://wiki.52north.org/Documentation/MavenIssues -> check this out if you use open jdk or by chance don't have the SSL certificates available you might need to point to them and try (instead of ignoring)

Comment: I use Oracle Java

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while running maven clean just to discover later that it was my Organization firewall that was causing the ACCESS_DENIED to be thrown from the AbstractHTTPClient. If you are running behind a company firewall can you update your settings.xml with the Firewall settings.

Check if you are running behind your company proxy. If yes then you may need to add your organization's proxy settings in settings.xml.

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>SOME ID</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>PROXY_HOST</host>
      <port>PROXY_PORT</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Comment: You may also find this answer helpful since your environment is Ubuntu https://stackoverflow.com/a/15409993/1430428

Comment: I am just a college student and tried it at home and in college :/

Comment: Great idea with adding the trustStore but it also didn't help. But still thank you!

Comment: Just searched oracle community for the truststore and found this https://community.oracle.com/thread/1534131. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This normally works out of the box. Either your JDK cacerts file (JDK_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts) is corrupted or someone is intercepting your network traffic and replacing TLS certificate used by Maven Central (common in a corporate environment).

Inspect the cacerts file using `keytool` shipped with your JDK and confirm that the certificate chain used by Maven Central is trusted. You can open [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/) in the web browser and inspect the actual TLS certificate. If you trust it, add it to your JDK cacerts.

Comment: I am just a college student and tried it at home and in college :/

Sorry for this question, but could you maybe explain how I inspect the cacerts? And how would I add the TLS from Maven? Thank you very much!

Comment: @justtoplayslow see https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html and https://superuser.com/a/347614

Comment: As in sslhopper stated i used Portecle to check my cacerts. Please check my edit in the Post. Thank you!