# Java runtime error in Ubuntu - Where in a code to put javax.net.ssl.trustStore?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I used this Java code from [here](http://www.codejava.net/coding/swing-application-to-download-files-from-http-server-with-progress-bar) and when I try to download a file with Google Disk shared link with https I get an error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected
>   error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the
>   trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

As I understand, I have to set in the code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/security/cacerts");
```

Where in the code I have to put it and what if I run it on Windows PC later?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution for me on Ubuntu 18.04 was this commnet from @jsn on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty):

> I ran sudo `rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` and then `sudo
>   update-ca-certificates -f` and this fixed my issue in kubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you use Tomcat you should add trustStore properties to `setenv.sh`.

On Ubuntu/Debian:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

On CentOS/RH the path is different:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts
```

Note that `cacerts` keystore is not generated by default on Ubuntu. You need to install `ca-certificates-java`

```
apt-get update
apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

Note that above will install some Java (JDK 11 on Ubuntu 20). So to keep your previous version you might need change your java path in `/etc/alternatives` (the file `/etc/alternatives/java` is a link).