# Unable to perform maven update for spring boot project in STS

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot application and imported it into the STS. but when i tried to perform "Maven Update", it shows the following error in pom.xml file as well as didnt get updated. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The error is as follows:-

```
**
```

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.3.RELEASE
>   from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.3.RELEASE
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty and 'parent.relativePath' points at no
>   local POM

**

This is my **pom.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DigitalEmployeeDB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>DigitalEmployeeDB</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/kernel  for Pdf Generation-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi  for Excel Generation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-beta5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Comment: can you share your pom.xml file ?

Comment: Yeah! i have added the pom.xml file contents. Please have a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue on my office laptop. They say, its due to some blockage by the firewall. Some network config should be done to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall default-jdk on Ubuntu. And i solved it.

Please refer to following link.

> [Maven: trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty and 'parent.relativePath' @ InvalidAlgorithmParameterException @ Non-resolvable parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571685/maven-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty-and-parent-relativepath-inva)

Answer (score -1):

create setting.xml at location "${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml"

Then add your office maven central repository as shown below

```
<settings>
 ...
 <profiles>
   ...
   <profile>
     <id>myprofile</id>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>my-repo2</id>
         <name>your custom repo</name>
         <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
   ...
 </profiles>

 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
 ...
</settings>
```

Comment: [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.springframework:gs-spring-boot:0.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.3.RELEASE from/to my-repo2 (http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk): jarsm2.dyndns.dk: Name or service not known and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 13