# Ubuntu 18.04: Pyspark UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES: module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to execute a spark script with the following command.

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 src/sparkProcessing.py
```

And I am getting 'Unresolved dependency error as show below.

I am using Spark 2.3.0, Scala 2.12 and Kafka 1.1.0

Following is the error which I am getting:

```
    :: modules in use:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.3.0


http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10/2.3.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.3.0.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.3.0: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


    :::: ERRORS
Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10/2.3.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.3.0.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty)

Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10/2.3.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.3.0.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty)


    :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.3.0: not found]
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1270)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688351/5808464

I purged the other java alternatives and install openjdk which I had earlier removed it myself.

Comment: And then offcourse put the kafka-streaming jar in the jars folder of spark.