# Broken URL for installing scala plugins

Tags: scala, chisel

I am trying to install rocket-chip and chisel3 is a submodule in that git repo. I followed the steps in 
[Chisel3 git repo](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3#installation)

I get the following error when I use

```
sbt compile
```

The project/plugins.sbt of chisel3 repo has

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("scalasbt", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases")) (Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

The URL is broken. I replaced it with https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases
Yet I see that I get this

```
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ... [info] Loading project definition from /home/sathya/riscv/rocket-chip/chisel3/project [info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/sathya/riscv/rocket-chip/chisel3/project/"), "chisel3-build")... [warn] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn] :: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES :: [warn] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn] :: org.scalastyle#scalastyle-sbt-plugin;1.0.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.scalastyle#scalastyle-sbt-plugin;1.0.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: [warn] typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.scalastyle#scalastyle-sbt-plugin;1.0.0: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalastyle/scalastyle-sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty [warn] sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.scalastyle#scalastyle-sbt-plugin;1.0.0: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scalastyle/scalastyle-sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty [warn] public: unable to get resource for org/scalastyle#scalastyle-sbt-plugin;1.0.0: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalastyle/scalastyle-sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/1.0.0/scalastyle-sbt-plugin-1.0.0.pom: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty [warn] sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.scalastyle#scalastyle-sbt-plugin;1.0.0: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scalastyle/scalastyle-sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty [warn] :: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.1: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.5.1 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
```

Can you please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: Apologies for missing this when you posted it. Can you provide more about your environment (especially OS)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on another thread I got this
"
error says "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty", which is a known issue on Linux. See  for various workarounds posted. [trustanchors error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)
"

Answer (score 0):

[I'm trying to compile chisel3 on MacOS High Sierra. Sbt was installed using brew.]

It seems even https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases is broken. I did the same but got a different error, for example:

[error] unresolved dependency: org.webjars#webjars-locator-core;0.32: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.webjars#webjars-locator-core;0.32 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.webjars#webjars-locator-core;0.32: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.32/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.webjars#webjars-locator-core;0.32: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.32/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.webjars#webjars-locator-core;0.32: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.32/jars/webjars-locator-core.jar: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.webjars#webjars-locator-core;0.32: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.32/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Visit https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.32/ivys/ivy.xml in a browser, it redirects to https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.32/ivys/ivy.xml and finally shows "The requested path was not found."