# Synchronize gradle project with workspace

Tags: eclipse, liferay, gradle-eclipse

am a newbie with Liferay on Eclipse, each time i try to carete a new liferay module project i get the following error. Am running Ubuntu 18.

Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error connecting to the Gradle build.
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip'.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty), 
there are many solutions so i will paste the exact one that did it for me.

First remove conflicting packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk* java-common default-jdk
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Check weather you successfully removed all related packages by:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

The system shall prompt you there is no Java available to config, otherwise this workaround fails.

Then reinstall required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```