# Netbeans 9 Maven Resource Plugin Dependancy Could Not Be Resolved?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a maven project that I was building in Netbeans 8 that compiled before moving to Netbeans 9.

Netbeans 9 is running Java 10 and so is my project (I changed this after moving to Netbeans 9) and the POM says that it is running version 10 as well.

When I try to build the project I get this error message though:

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Building Stellar 1.0
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Downloading:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 0.456 s Finished at: 2018-07-29T16:48:26-04:00 Final
>   Memory: 7M/34M
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

This is my POM:

```
> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Stellar</groupId>
    <artifactId>Stellar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.40.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.protonmail.sarahszabo.stellaropusconverter.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>Shaded</shadedClassifierName> <!-- Any name that makes sense -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>`
```

How can i resolve this?

**Edit 0:**

Created a sample test maven project with a default main method. It failed with a similar error:

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not
>   transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]

The sample POM:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Edit 1: ** Outout of Terminal `mvn clean install`

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4
>   or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]

IDE (Netbeans 9) Log After Attempt at Clean & Build:

```
> INFO [org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl]:
> Downloaded maven index file has size 0 (zipped). The usable space in
> /home/sarah/.cache/netbeans/9.0 is 222,938,177,536. INFO
> [org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl]: could
> not (re-)index central
> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
> parameter must be non-empty   at
> java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
>   at
> java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
>   at
> java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:86)
> Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error  at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:89)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:180)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:192)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:133)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.checkServerCerts(ClientHandshaker.java:1947)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.certificateStatus(ClientHandshaker.java:1798)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:276)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1098)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processRecord(Handshaker.java:1026)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.processInputRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1137)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1074)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1429)
> Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLException    at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:214)    at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1974)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1926)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1909)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1436)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:254)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:832)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:983)
> Caused: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
> parameter must be non-empty   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
>   at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
>   at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)  at
> org.apache.maven.index.updater.WagonHelper$WagonFetcher.retrieve(WagonHelper.java:220)
> Caused: java.io.IOException: Transfer for
> nexus-maven-repository-index.properties failed;
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
> parameter must be non-empty   at
> org.apache.maven.index.updater.WagonHelper$WagonFetcher.retrieve(WagonHelper.java:245)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.index.updater.WagonHelper$WagonFetcher.retrieve(WagonHelper.java:202)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.downloadIndexProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:342)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.access$000(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:76)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater$IndexAdaptor.setProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:465)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:681)
>   at
> org.apache.maven.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:161)
>   at
> org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.indexLoadedRepo(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:529)
>   at
> org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.access$200(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:123)
> [catch] at
> org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl$3.run(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:660)
>   at
> org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl$3.run(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:653)
>   at
> org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.DefaultMutexImplementation.writeAccess(DefaultMutexImplementation.java:229)
>   at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeAccess(Mutex.java:246)   at
> org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.indexRepo(NexusRepositoryIndexerImpl.java:653)
>   at
> org.netbeans.modules.maven.indexer.api.RepositoryIndexer.indexRepo(RepositoryIndexer.java:42)
>   at
> org.netbeans.modules.maven.ProjectOpenedHookImpl$2.run(ProjectOpenedHookImpl.java:207)
>   at
> org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
>   at
> org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
>   at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)    at
> org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.5/jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/org/controlsfx/controlsfx/8.40.14/controlsfx-8.40.14.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.7/commons-lang3-3.7.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.9.0/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.9.0.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.6/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.6/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.6/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.5/jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/org/controlsfx/controlsfx/8.40.14/controlsfx-8.40.14.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.7/commons-lang3-3.7.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.9.0/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.9.0.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.6/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.6/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar!/
> WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.maven.nodes.DependenciesNode]: Could not
> determine module name for artifact
> jar:file:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.6/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar!/
```

Comment: First question: Does it build successful on plain command line?

Comment: I've never used command line tools to build a maven project. Could you instruct me on how to do this? I've only used the clean and build or run buttons.

Comment: For most setups, in order to build manually, `cd`into your project's root directory (contains the `src` directory), run `mvn build` (assuming maven is installed on your system).

Comment: [1] You have some invalid junk at the start of line 1 in your listing of pom.xml [2] I copied your pom (except for that junk) to a test project on NB9/JDK10 and it built without problems, so the problem presumably lies with your environment. Perhaps you have a network or firewall issue to get that **InvalidAlgorithmParameterException**? [3] Try creating a smaller simpler Maven project with a single dependency to see if that also fails. [4] Search SO for **InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty** to see if any of the solutions apply to you.

Comment: @DoeJohnson When I do this I get `[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "build". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are:` and it lists a bunch of options.

Comment: @skomisa Just checked ufw status, it's offline. Also, created a new project with only a test-main and a default, untouched POM, and it failed with a similar error.

Comment: @SarahSzabo OK. Do you still have NetBeans 8.2 on  your machine? If so, can you still successfully build that same project on NB8.2 right now? If you can then the problem must lie with your NB9 configuration. Two things to check: [1] **Tools > Options > General** then verify that your **Proxy Settings** on NB9 are the same as on NB8.2. [2] On NB9 open the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) then rebuild the project again. Do you see any relevant new error messages being logged?

Comment: @SarahSzabo Also, you could try doing `mvn clean install` from the command line instead of `mvn build`. It worked for me. (I have never used `mvn build`.)

Comment: @skomisa I can still build the project on NB 8.2, just not on 9. The proxy settings are both set to use No Proxy, and I don't use a system proxy anyway. I made a post of the logs that popped up on NB 9 after attempting to clean and build.

Comment: @SarahSzabo OK. Can you also try `mvn clean install` from the command line for your project to build it using Java 10? If that also fails then the issue is probably related to your JDK10 setup rather than NetBeans 9. Also, compare your Maven settings on NB8.2 and NB9 using **Tools > Options > Java > Maven** tab. (The only difference for me is that NB9 is bundled with Maven 3.3.9, but NB8.2 uses 3.0.5 which is fine.)

Comment: @skomisa Yep, I posted the output of `mvn clean install` from the Terminal. I can't understand why it would be related to my JDK10 install. It was installed from the terminal and automatically set as the default JDK. I haven't touched/configured it in any way. That and Netbeans 8.2 builds it, but Netbeans 9 can't. Where should i go from here?

Comment: @SarahSzabo OK, then it looks like your problem is with your JDK10 installation rather than NetBeans 9, so just focus on getting `mvn clean install` to work first. If you are on Linux, and in particular Ubuntu, look at the many answers for [Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6784463/2985643). Be sure to make only one change at a time so if you get `mvn clean install` working you know what change solved the problem. To be clear, I am using Windows 10 so that post is not relevant for me (nor for you if you are also using Windows).

Comment: @skomisa I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688351/2058221 's answer fixed the issue. If you post the link as an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it as the answer :)

Comment: @SarahSzabo That's great! But please post an answer yourself, since: [1] You found the solution. [2] It's much more helpful to the community to have solutions in answers rather than comments. [3] I think you are the only person to have the problem with JDK 10 [4] The existing answer that fixed your issue was for a completely different problem.