# InvalidAlgorithmParameterException for openjdk 9

Tags: java, java-9

Windows, Java project, using OpenJDK 9, when I tried to run `maven clean`, got the error below. I checked the file cacerts exists in C:\Program Files\Java\java-se-9-ri\jdk-9\lib\security. How to fix the error?

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:  
    Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5:
    Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
        java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Comment: I found an answer. need to get the certificates for the website https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/, then export the certificates, then import it.