# JetBrains ToolBox unable to update Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I recently downloaded Jetbrains toolbox to update Jetbrains IDEs.  When I open toolbox, it says displays an update button next to pycharm, but when I click update, it gives me the following error message: "Download failed. Unexpected Error:java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty."

I was wondering why this is happening and how I can fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, as I have win10 and most of the solutions are for linux