# Android Studio 4.X.1 with error trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, capacitor

Guys I have started with stater project on Ionic using Capacitor. Trying to build Android build and seems like Android studio is failing with Gradle issues.

I have done below

ionic capacitor run android

My build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Issue:

```
Executing tasks: [build] in project /somelocation/android


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 436ms
22:23:51: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

I am able build the project using Ionic commands but I would like to run this on emulator hence trying to open it on Android studio. When I try to import using android studio gradle sync dies with above exception. Any direction on this issue would help.

Comment: Any clue about this issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Comment: You should have properly tagged this question with `android`, then it would already be closed.

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to run java -jar or set some website manually while running gradle sync / build. This is even happening when I am creating fresh project through android studio.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved. This error was happening when I am running projects with OpenJDK version openjdk-8u41-b04-linux-x64-14_jan_2020. Once I change it to use OpenJDK 14.0.2 it worked fine.