# Elasticsearch high-level REST client fails to connect over https

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect Elastic over https using high-level REST client. But the clients fails with below exception.

```
java.io.IOException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:884)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:283)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1632)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1617)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:974)
    at org.me.elastic.ElasticSSLClient.createIndexes(ElasticSSLClient.java:70)
    at org.me.elastic.ElasticSSLClient.main(ElasticSSLClient.java:34)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.convert(SSLIOSession.java:262)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doWrap(SSLIOSession.java:269)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:305)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:523)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:99)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:300)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:176)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:246)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1334)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1174)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:285)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:345)
    ... 9 more
```

I have setup a git repo with [java client code](https://github.com/shivchelwa/elastic-ssl-client). I used the step mentioned on [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/configuring-tls.html) to setup TLS and HTTPS on my Mac. Added below properties and elasticsearch startups fine.

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12

xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elasticsearch/http.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: certs/elasticsearch/http.p12
```

Also, used the [code sample](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_encrypted_communication.html) from elasticsearch docs. Something wrong with client code or HTTPS setup?

Comment: You may find your answer here [trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is the way Keystore instance is build. While creating the pkcs12 store, I did not use a password, hence I was passing a null while loading certificates.

```
    KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(trustStorePath)) {
        truststore.load(is, null);
    }
```

But when I changed is to a empty string, certificates were loaded and connected to the elasticsearch.

```
    KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(trustStorePath)) {
        truststore.load(is, "".toCharArray());
    }
```