# Maven test run in Eclipse does not work . Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

A test in Eclipse / JUnit with a Maven project run as "Maven test" using Surefire PlugIn does not work. See error code below.

I did not find any solution but one saying using Oracle jdk it works but openjdk is a must have in this case.

Any idea what´s wrong?

Running versions:

MAVEN:

> Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d) Maven
> home: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin.. Java version:
> 15.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\path_to_folders\software\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.
> hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre Default
> locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 10",
> version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

JAVA:
openjdk version "1.8.0_41"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_41-b04)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

SUREFIRE:
maven-surefire-plugin 3.0.0-M5

ECLIPSE IDE:
Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
Build id: 20210312-0638

Error Code:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< de.condingsolo:SeleniumMavenProjekt1 >----------------
[INFO] Building SeleniumMavenProjekt1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SeleniumMavenProjekt1 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SeleniumMavenProjekt1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SeleniumMavenProjekt1 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SeleniumMavenProjekt1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ SeleniumMavenProjekt1 ---
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/3.0.0-M5/maven-surefire-common-3.0.0-M5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.798 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-30T17:07:09+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project SeleniumMavenProjekt1: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M5 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:3.0.0-M5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:3.0.0-M5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:pom:3.0.0-M5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/3.0.0-M5/maven-surefire-common-3.0.0-M5.pom: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I think it is all about this part:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project SeleniumMavenProjekt1: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M5 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:3.0.0-M5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:3.0.0-M5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:pom:3.0.0-M5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/3.0.0-M5/maven-surefire-common-3.0.0-M5.pom: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.condingsolo</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumMavenProjekt1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 

  </dependency>
    
    
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>


</project>
```

Java Build Path in Screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkgjO.png)

Java Build Path Libraries Screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKSSp.png)

Comment: Check it out with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty

Answer (score 0):

See this [Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

Your original problem `InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty` was related to SSL and keystore password. Freely it could be related to your **settings.xml** or SSL certificates because your local repo already contains the most of required artifacts but new artifacts could not be downloaded.