# Bitbucket Pipeline CLI command return "the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

Tags: java, bitbucket, pipeline, truststore, sslexception

I am trying to run an CLI command from one of my packages installed in a Bitbucket Pipeline in a cloud hosted server which I do not have access to. That command should push a bunch of files to a remote server.

The pipeline always fail with

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException:
> the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

I have seen the following post on bitbucket and stack overflow
[SSL Connection fail](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/ssl-connections-fail-from-jira-server-to-external-systems-218269293.html)

[Unable to execute outbound SSL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/unable-to-establish-outbound-ssl-connections-due-to-java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-969519474.html)

[Error - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty)

And it looks like I need to execute some command on the server, but as my hosting is cloud, and since I do not quite fully understand what this is (it looks like JAVA ? but on my machine the command work and I do not have JAVA installed ?) I wonder what could I do to make it works, I have no knowledge in this domain.

I contacted bitbucket, which pointed me to [Here](https://medium.com/@gustavocalcaterra/debugging-yet-another-ssl-tls-error-the-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty-7dd9cb300f43)
telling me to use You need to use the properties `javax.net.debug=all` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/Truststore` to debug the issue.

but again, I do not have java installed in my machine, and it works. also I am using a simple image `image: circleci/node:12-browsers` which do not include java, so `java/javax` command are no found. And I am stuck.

Thank your for your help.

Comment: It seems the image has java installed. Can you tell me what commands you are trying to run?

```
Andreis-MacBook-Pro:my-first-app adumitrescu$ docker run --rm -it circleci/node:12-browsers bash
_XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.
circleci@8d33d7921d27:/$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Debian-1bpo91)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Debian-1bpo91, mixed mode, sharing)
circleci@8d33d7921d27:/$
```

Comment: I actually solved this by using this image instead https://hub.docker.com/r/nathanfriend/java-node-git/

I wish there was an official image with this

Comment: I do not know the command that run inside the cli command, but just `java -version` was doing c>command not found with `node:12`

Comment: I see in docker hub pretty much all the circleCI:node images are updated 12 hr ago, maybe re-pull the image or try to use a different one, e.g. circleci/node:16.5-browsers