# The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 9001 failed to start

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to implement SSL into my microservice but when i'm adding ssl configuration into application.yml file then getting following error:

[image: error after running application]

This is application.yml file:

[image: This is my application.yml file]

but when i remove configurations related to trust store then it runs successfully but along with trust store configurations. I need these configurations. please suggest me show to solve this problem.

Comment: Please share spring boot version

Comment: @AshishPatil, Spring boot version is 2.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: shared my answer as this problem is more or less related to version compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You have to update spring boot version from your `2.0.3.RELEASE` to `2.4.2` or higher. Release version `2.0.3.RELEASE` is little bit old & I am using `2.4.2` with SSL without any issue.

Comment: After adding 2.4.2 now i'm getting this error while running application
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Comment: @user979879, it means your truststore was unable to locate at a path which you have mentioned in your property file. Can you put your jks files inside your project folder & remove `classpath` & check if error still appears?

Comment: Other option for this, if truststore is not added at all : https://www.baeldung.com/java-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty

Comment: @Ashil Patil, It alredy in the resources folder and i also added the absolute path of it like src/mian/resources/cert.jks but still getting same error

Comment: spring boot will scan resources folder for checking file. so ideally it should only like `key-store` :  `cert.jks` .  You don't need to give `src/main`

Comment: after removing src/main it is only searching into root folder not in resources. let me move it to the root folder

Comment: after moving to root folder again same error is coming

Comment: @user979879, spring boot will by default search for `src/main/resources ` folder.  I hope you have that folder?

Comment: so, in nutshell, have `src/main/resources` folder, put your `application.yml` there. put your jks files in root folder i.e. where project starts & let me know if still error. Make sure use files without classpath

Comment: yes i have resources but it is not searching into that directly after adding classpath it able to find it but its getting same error

Comment: i did the same thing which you said still getting error

Comment: have you removed classpath from yml?

Comment: Yes i removed it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty based on this common answer, this error is either file is not found or your `jks` files password is wrong or `jks` itself has no content. 
Can you try to use `keytool` and check if `jks` files has any entries at all?

Comment: the path is correct. i verified it. Also i checked jks file it containing all the infomation

Comment: well, it looks like we have exhausted all options here. can you recreate this project in new workspace with updated spring version which i mentioned above?

Comment: Sure, I will check that

Comment: can you tell me the size of your jks file because mine is only 3 kb?

Comment: @user979879, yes, its around same.