# Railo CFHTTP SSL the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: tomcat, railo, cfhttp, cfml

I'm trying to issue a CFHTTP Call (via SSL) with Railo 3.3 and am receiving the following error:

```
Unknown host: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

I tried the most basic call to a common website over ssl and get the same error. Here is my code

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/" method="get">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

It clearly has to do with the SSL. If you take out the **https** and replace it with **http**, the call works just fine.

Furthermore, this call (be it http or https) works fine on Adobe ColdFusion 9.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my server config:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5
- Railo 3.3

Comment: I would bet that something wrong with your JRE, most likely. Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764611/java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-trustanchors-parameter-mus

Comment: Might also dump your truststore path, just to verify it is valid `createObject("java", "java.lang.System").getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore")`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Log into the Railo Server Administrator by going to `http://yourdomain/railo-context/admin/server.cfm`
2. Go to the `SSL Certificates`
3. Add the domain you want to get the SSL certificate to the form (e.g. `www.google.com`) and click list (to make sure you can see the certificate)
4. Then add the certificate and try your code again.