# Why is my Maven archetype:generate failing?

Tags: maven, aem

I'm new to the CQ environment, but not Maven, Eclipse or Java, but I'm totally stumped. I'm trying to run through a couple tutorials for CQ and I'm having trouble on the first one:
Using CQ 5.6.1, Maven 3.2.5, and JDK 7.

I'm running the following Maven command to scaffold my first CQ project:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeRepository=adobe-public-releases \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.day.jcr.vault \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=multimodule-content-package-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2 \
-DgroupId=my-group-id \
-DartifactId=myproject \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
-Dpackage=com.mycompany.myproject \
-DappsFolderName=myproject \
-DartifactName="My Project" \
-DcqVersion="5.6.1" \
-DpackageGroup="My Company" -e -X
```

My ~/.m2/settings.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies></proxies>
  <servers></servers>
  <mirrors></mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <!-- ====================================================== -->
    <!-- A D O B E   P U B L I C   P R O F I L E                -->
    <!-- ====================================================== -->
    <profile>
      <id>adobe-public</id>

      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        <releaseRepository-Id>adobe-public-releases</releaseRepository-Id>
        <releaseRepository-Name>Adobe Public Releases</releaseRepository-Name>
        <releaseRepository-URL>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public</releaseRepository-URL>
      </properties>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>adobe-public-releases</id>
          <name>Adobe Public Repository</name>
          <url>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>

      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>adobe-public-releases</id>
          <name>Adobe Public Repository</name>
          <url>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>adobe-public</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.sonatype.plugins</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>com.day.jcr.vault</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>org.apache.sling</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>com.adobe.granite</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

[Pastebin link to my terminal output](http://pastebin.com/egA8exFb)

Comment: What's happening? Are you getting an error?

Comment: It looks from your output like you're running into SSL key generation errors when Maven tries to download dependencies. According to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162249/java-ssl-exception-prime-size-must-be-a-multiple-of-64) the error you are getting tends to affect Java < 8. Can you try with JDK 8 to eliminate possible root causes? I would also suggest creating a default keystore, if you don't have one yet, per [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764611/java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-trustanchors-parameter-mus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported as bug [JDK-7044060](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7044060) and fixed recently.