# Can't run app on emulator in react-native

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to run a simple simple project of react-native. I setup the environment and running into this error when I am attempting to run the program on the emulator.

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/shocky/NewReactNative/newRNP/node_modules (9ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1899)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:91)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:89)
    ... 26 more
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Whenever I run `react-native run-android` it produces the error. I have found some other people having the same issue. I have tried some solutions but it does not work.

I do have an emulator running.

I am using,
 Ubuntu 17.10.
 openjdk 8

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem with Linux. The issue is with the jre installation that Android is using and its certs. This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764611/java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-trustanchors-parameter-mus) already. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Then, try this:

```
sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

Comment: The question has already said, "I am using, Ubuntu 17.10. openjdk 8".