# how to fix javacord error java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException

Tags: java, discord, bots

I make Discord Bot.
it works good in Netbeans 8.2 IDE. But Export .jar and Execute this, it didn't work about with error.

```
Caused By: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
           at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
           at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
           at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:89)
           ... 45 more
2020-12-23 04:34:15.719+0900 INFO.org.javacord.core.util.gateway.DiscordWebSocketAdapter Trying to reconnet/resume in ~~ seconds! [shard=0]
```

I coded it Java Version 1.8.0_144.

Here is my Discord Bot main Source.

```
...
        try {
        DiscordApiBuilder builder = new DiscordApiBuilder();
        builder = builder.setToken(DiscordSetting.discordBotSetting.getFirst());
        api = builder.login().join(); // this line is error
        api.addListener(new Discordcommand());
        api.updateActivity(ActivityType.PLAYING, "=help");
        DiscordGeneralChat chat = new DiscordGeneralChat();
        ChatHandler.addListener(chat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

...
```

I tryed many way answered fix to code..:(
I'll try anything that helps.

Thank you.

Comment: I used OS 'Windows 10'

Answer (score 0):

You look like you're using linux, you need to use this command:
`sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java`
[(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764611/java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-trustanchors-parameter-mus)

Comment: Oh, I used OS 'Window 10'. 
I'm sorry I couldn't say in the text

Comment: What JDK are you using? I would recommend you to try using AdoptOpenJDK.

Comment: I use OpenJDK. I try changed cacerts file to oracle but I get the same error.